# Translate 3D vector to another plane

Tags: vector, 3d, plane

I have planes defined using normal(point is allways zero (0,0,0)). Plane normal is actually a up vector for few vectors which need to be translated to another plane.

I was trying to find a way how to translate these few vectors from first plane to second plane.

Comment: planes are defined using point,normal. If you want to translate a plane just translate the point. The normal is not affected by the translation.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13032296/1756636