# Coordinates transformation

Tags: matrix, coordinates, transformation, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I have two 3D objects in space and i want to copy the points from one object to another. The problem is that these objects don't share a common coordinate system and i have to do coordinate transformations. I have the local transformation matrix for both objects and i have also access to the world transformation matrix. I know there's some calculations to be done using these transformation matrices but i don't know how.

How can i transform one point in the first object so that it has the same position(relative to the world coordinates) if i copy it in the other object( or its coordinate system )?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to apply the conversion operator that you have.
E.g., the relation between polar (r, t) and cartesian (x, y) coordinates is defined by:

```
x = rcost
y = rsint
```

Comment: do you know how this could be done using transformation matrices?

Comment: You'll need to perform some linear algebra - multiply the point coordinates by the transformation matrix to get the coordinates in the second system.

Comment: Can you please give some details?
So I have a vector of 3 floats containing my xyz coordinates relative to the source shape and 3 transformation matrixex: of the origin shape, of the target shape and of the world.
How can i get the 3float vector to contain the coordinates relative to the target shape?

Comment: First of all, there is no such thing as "transformation matrix of something". Transformation matrix is from coordinates system a to coordinates system b. So let's say you want to transform `(x,y,z)` to target `(x',y',z')`. You'll need to multiply the matrix A which describes the transformation (that would be one of your matrices) by `(x,y,z)` vector. If you want to do another translation, multiply the relevant matrix by `(x',y',z')`.

Comment: yes, but when you multiply a vector by a matrix, the result is a matrix. which matrix's points are the one i need?

Comment: i think i'm wrong, when you multiply a matrix to a vector you get a matrix and when you multiply a vector by a matrix you get a vector, am i right or wrong?

Comment: You must multiply matrix `A` by vector `v`, not vice versa. Order is important in vectors/matrices multiplication. `A*v != v*A`, multiplication is not commutative!

Comment: so if i have to multiply matrix `A` by vector `v` i get another matrix. which points of the resulting matrix are the ones i need(the ones representing the 3 points of vector `v` in the destination coordinate system)?

Comment: No, you'll get a vector `v'` corresponding to your original vector `v`

Comment: Pleas excuse my insistence but i don't understand.

I have a vector `v` and a matrix `A` and i multiply them and i get another matrix `A'` for example. But what i need are 3 resulting points. I assumed that the resulting points i need are represented in a row or column of the resulting matrix, that's why i asked 'which points of the resulting matrix are the ones i need'.

You say 'you'll get a vector `v'` corresponding to your original vector v', how can i calculate that vector `v'` you're referring to and which contain the resulting coordinates?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18534/discussion-between-john-smith-and-icepack)

Comment: `A*v=v'`. See here for a simple explanation: http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/mastascu/elessonsHTML/Circuit/MatVecMultiply.htm

Answer (score 1):

I'm about 9 years late but I had to solve the same problem.

Use a homogeneous transformation matrix. To do this first calculate a 4x4 rotation matrix using the unit vectors describing the local cs using values with respect to the global cs. Then calculate a similar 4x4 translation matrix. Then the transformation matrix is simply the dot product of the translation and rotation matrices. Calculating the inverse of a homogeneous transformation matrix is not quite so simple. I found the University of [Illinois robotics class](http://motion.cs.illinois.edu/RoboticSystems/CoordinateTransformations.html) notes helped me understand what was required. Of course the details can really trip you up so I feel compelled to render the details as python code.

Let's call the following code "transform_coord_sys.py":

```
# Functions to convert points etc from one coordinate system to another
#
# These functions are based on a 4x4 homogeneous matrices or
# homogeneous coordinates introduced by August Ferdinand Möbius
# See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates
#
# Other work I found useful in developing this code includes:
# University of Illinois Robotics course http://motion.cs.illinois.edu/RoboticSystems/CoordinateTransformations.html

import numpy as np


def unit_vector(xyz_array):
    """
    Compute unit vector of vector from origin to specified xyz point
    :param xyz_array: numpy array of length 3. x = 1st element, y = 2nd element, z = 3rd element
    :return: xyz_unit : unit vector (ie ijk) in specified direction
    """
    num_xyz = len(xyz_array)
    if num_xyz != 3:
        raise ValueError('Input array to "unit_vector" must have length of 3.')

    xyz_unit = xyz_array / np.linalg.norm(xyz_array)

    return xyz_unit


def create_rotation_matrix_from_points(local_origin, local_x_dir, local_xy_plane):
    """
    Create a 4x4 homogeneous rotation matrix 
    :param local_origin: np_array of x,y,z wrt global cs
    :param local_x_dir:  np_array of x,y,z point. vector from local_origin to this point defines X
    :param local_xy_plane: point in xy plane
    :return: rot_matrix: homogeneous rotation matrix
    """
    local_x_vec = local_x_dir - local_origin
    local_unit_x = unit_vector(local_x_vec)

    local_xy_vec = local_xy_plane - local_origin
    local_z_vec = np.cross(local_x_vec, local_xy_vec)
    local_unit_z = unit_vector(local_z_vec)

    local_y_vec = np.cross(local_z_vec, local_x_vec)
    local_unit_y = unit_vector(local_y_vec)

    # print('local_unit_x = {}'.format(local_unit_x))
    # print('local_unit_y = {}'.format(local_unit_y))
    # print('local_unit_z = {}'.format(local_unit_z))

    rot_matrix = np.zeros((4, 4))
    rot_matrix[3, 3] = 1.0
    rot_matrix[0:3, 0] = local_unit_x
    rot_matrix[0:3, 1] = local_unit_y
    rot_matrix[0:3, 2] = local_unit_z
    determinant = np.linalg.det(rot_matrix)
    assert np.isclose(determinant, 1.0)

    # print('rot_matrix = \n{}'.format(rot_matrix))
    # print('determinant = {}\n'.format(determinant))

    return rot_matrix


def create_translation_matrix_from_point(point, origin=np.zeros(3)):
    """
    Create a 4x4 homogeneous translation matrix
    :param point: np_array of x,y,z wrt global cs
    :param origin:  np_array of x,y,z point. vector from local_origin to this point defines X
    :return: translation_matrix : homogeneous translation matrix
    """
    translation_matrix = np.identity(4)
    deltas = point - origin
    translation_matrix[0:3, 3] = deltas

    # print('translation_matrix = \n{}'.format(translation_matrix))

    return translation_matrix


def invert_homogeneous_transformation_matrix(transformation_matrix):
    """
    Invert a homogeneous transformation matrix
    :param transformation_matrix: homogeneous transformation matrix
    :return: inverse_transform: inverted matrix
    """

    rot_matrix = transformation_matrix[0:3, 0:3]
    translation = transformation_matrix[0:3, 3]
    # for orthogonal arrays the transpose is equal to the inverse
    rot_inverse = rot_matrix.transpose()

    trans_inv = -rot_inverse.dot(translation)

    inverse_transform = np.identity(4)
    inverse_transform[0:3, 0:3] = rot_inverse
    inverse_transform[0:3, 3] = trans_inv

    return inverse_transform


def calculate_homogeneous_transforms(local_origin, local_x_dir, local_xy_plane):

    rot_matrix_4x4 = create_rotation_matrix_from_points(local_origin, local_x_dir, local_xy_plane)
    translation_matrix = create_translation_matrix_from_point(local_origin)

    # This is the key step showing how the transformation_matrix is created
    # using matrix multiplication of the translation and rotation matrices.
    # Order is CRITICAL:
    #     translation_matrix.dot(rot_matrix_4x4) IS NOT EQUAL TO rot_matrix_4x4.dot(translation_matrix)
    #     (except it trivial cases where it provides the correct answer but is still wrong)
    transformation_matrix = translation_matrix.dot(rot_matrix_4x4)
    inverse_transform = invert_homogeneous_transformation_matrix(transformation_matrix)

    return transformation_matrix, inverse_transform


def test_pure_rotation():
    print('{}'.format('-'*80))
    print('testing test_pure_rotation')

    local_origin = np.asarray([0.0, 0.0, .0])
    local_x_dir = np.asarray([0.0,  1.0, 0.0])
    local_xy_plane = np.asarray([-1.0, 1.0, 0.0])

    print('    local_origin = {}'.format(local_origin))
    print('    local_x_dir = {}'.format(local_x_dir))
    print('    local_xy_plane = {}'.format(local_xy_plane))

    transformation_matrix, inverse_transform = calculate_homogeneous_transforms(local_origin,
                                                                                local_x_dir,
                                                                                local_xy_plane)

    tm_str = '     {}'.format(transformation_matrix)
    tm_str = tm_str.replace('\n', '\n     ')
    print('\n    transformation_matrix = \n{}'.format(tm_str))

    point = np.asarray([1.0, 1.0, 2, 1.0])

    point_local = inverse_transform.dot(point)
    print('\n    point {} in local cs = {}'.format(point, point_local))

    point_global = transformation_matrix.dot(point_local)
    print('    local point {} in global cs = {}\n'.format(point_local, point_global))

    assert np.isclose(point, point_global).all()
    assert np.isclose(point_local, [1.0, -1, 2, 1.]).all()

    print('    Successfully completed test of test_pure_rotation\n')
    return None


def test_pure_translation():
    print('{}'.format('-'*80))
    print('testing test_pure_translation')

    local_origin = np.asarray([0.0, 0.0, 1.0])
    local_x_dir = np.asarray([1.0,  0, 1.0])
    local_xy_plane = np.asarray([0.0, 1.0, 1.0])

    print('    local_origin = {}'.format(local_origin))
    print('    local_x_dir = {}'.format(local_x_dir))
    print('    local_xy_plane = {}'.format(local_xy_plane))

    transformation_matrix, inverse_transform = calculate_homogeneous_transforms(local_origin,
                                                                                local_x_dir,
                                                                                local_xy_plane)

    tm_str = '     {}'.format(transformation_matrix)
    tm_str = tm_str.replace('\n', '\n     ')
    print('\n    transformation_matrix = \n{}'.format(tm_str))
    point = np.asarray([1.0, 1.0, 0, 1.0])

    point_local = inverse_transform.dot(point)
    print('\n    point {} in local cs = {}'.format(point, point_local))

    point_global = transformation_matrix.dot(point_local)
    print('    local point {} in global cs = {}\n'.format(point_local, point_global))

    assert np.isclose(point, point_global).all()
    assert np.isclose(point_local, [1.0, 1, -1, 1.]).all()

    print('    Successfully completed test of test_pure_translation\n')
    return None


def test_rotation_and_translation():
    print('{}'.format('-'*80))
    print('testing test_rotation_and_translation')

    local_origin = np.asarray([1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
    local_x_dir = np.asarray([.0,  1, 1.0])
    local_xy_plane = np.asarray([1.0, 2.0, 1.0])

    print('    local_origin = {}'.format(local_origin))
    print('    local_x_dir = {}'.format(local_x_dir))
    print('    local_xy_plane = {}'.format(local_xy_plane))

    transformation_matrix, inverse_transform = calculate_homogeneous_transforms(local_origin,
                                                                                local_x_dir,
                                                                                local_xy_plane)

    tm_str = '     {}'.format(transformation_matrix)
    tm_str = tm_str.replace('\n', '\n     ')
    print('\n    transformation_matrix = \n{}'.format(tm_str))

    point = np.asarray([-1.0, 2.0, 2, 1.0])
    # point = np.asarray([1.0, 1.0, 1, 1.0])
    # point = np.asarray([0.0, 0.0, 1, 1.0])

    point_local = inverse_transform.dot(point)
    print('\n    point {} in local cs = {}'.format(point, point_local))

    point_global = transformation_matrix.dot(point_local)
    print('    local point {} in global cs = {}\n'.format(point_local, point_global))

    assert np.isclose(point, point_global).all()
    assert np.isclose(point_local, [2.0, 1, -1, 1.]).all()

    print('    Successfully completed test of test_rotation_and_translation\n')
    return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_pure_rotation()
    test_pure_translation()
    test_rotation_and_translation()
    print('')
```

Now the test cases result in very simple output and show how a single point can be transformed from one coordinate system to the other.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
testing test_pure_rotation
    local_origin = [0. 0. 0.]
    local_x_dir = [0. 1. 0.]
    local_xy_plane = [-1.  1.  0.]

    transformation_matrix = 
     [[ 0. -1.  0.  0.]
      [ 1.  0.  0.  0.]
      [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
      [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]]

    point [1. 1. 2. 1.] in local cs = [ 1. -1.  2.  1.]
    local point [ 1. -1.  2.  1.] in global cs = [1. 1. 2. 1.]

    Successfully completed test of test_pure_rotation

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
testing test_pure_translation
    local_origin = [0. 0. 1.]
    local_x_dir = [1. 0. 1.]
    local_xy_plane = [0. 1. 1.]

    transformation_matrix = 
     [[1. 0. 0. 0.]
      [0. 1. 0. 0.]
      [0. 0. 1. 1.]
      [0. 0. 0. 1.]]

    point [1. 1. 0. 1.] in local cs = [ 1.  1. -1.  1.]
    local point [ 1.  1. -1.  1.] in global cs = [1. 1. 0. 1.]

    Successfully completed test of test_pure_translation

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
testing test_rotation_and_translation
    local_origin = [1. 1. 1.]
    local_x_dir = [0. 1. 1.]
    local_xy_plane = [1. 2. 1.]

    transformation_matrix = 
     [[-1.  0.  0.  1.]
      [ 0.  1.  0.  1.]
      [ 0.  0. -1.  1.]
      [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]]

    point [-1.  2.  2.  1.] in local cs = [ 2.  1. -1.  1.]
    local point [ 2.  1. -1.  1.] in global cs = [-1.  2.  2.  1.]

    Successfully completed test of test_rotation_and_translation
```

To use the code for multiple points at a time we can call the following code "example_transform_cs.py".

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import transform_coord_sys as tcs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    local_origin = np.asarray([1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
    local_x_dir = np.asarray([0, 1, 1.0])
    # local_x_dir = np.asarray([-7, 2, -3])
    local_xy_plane = np.asarray([1.0, 2.0, 1.0])

    print('    local_origin = {}'.format(local_origin))
    print('    local_x_dir = {}'.format(local_x_dir))
    print('    local_xy_plane = {}'.format(local_xy_plane))

    transformation_matrix, inverse_transform = tcs.calculate_homogeneous_transforms(local_origin,
                                                                                    local_x_dir,
                                                                                    local_xy_plane)

    tm_str = '     {}'.format(transformation_matrix)
    tm_str = tm_str.replace('\n', '\n     ')
    print('\n    transformation_matrix = \n{}'.format(tm_str))

    # all points have an extra dimension with the fourth item set to 1.0
    # this is to make them compatible with homogeneous transforms
    point = np.asarray([.4, 0.6, 0.7, 1.0])

    point_local = inverse_transform.dot(point)
    print('\n    point {} in local cs = {}'.format(point, point_local))

    point_global = transformation_matrix.dot(point_local)
    print('    local point {} in global cs = {}\n'.format(point_local, point_global))

    global_cs_line_x = np.asarray([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
    global_cs_line_y = np.asarray([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0])
    global_cs_line_z = np.asarray([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0])

    global_homogenous = np.ones(len(global_cs_line_x))

    global_cs_3d = np.concatenate((global_cs_line_x, global_cs_line_y,
                                   global_cs_line_z, global_homogenous)).reshape((4, 5))

    local_cs_3d = transformation_matrix.dot(global_cs_3d)

    ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')

    ax.plot(global_cs_line_x, global_cs_line_y, global_cs_line_z, label='global_cs')
    ax.plot(local_cs_3d[0, :], local_cs_3d[1, :], local_cs_3d[2, :], label='local_cs')
    ax.plot(point[0], point[1], point[2], label='point', marker='x', markersize=14)

    fig = plt.gcf()
    text = 'Point\nGlobal CS {}\nLocal CS {}'.format(point[0:3], point_local[0:3])
    fig.text(.1, .9, text, fontsize=8)

    # ax.set_box_aspect((np.ptp(xs), np.ptp(ys), np.ptp(zs)))  # aspect ratio is 1:1:1 in data space
    ax.set_box_aspect((1., 1., 1.))  # aspect ratio is 1:1:1 in data space
    ax.legend()

    plt.show()
```

The code creates a simple line representation of the unit vectors representing the global coordinate system and then transforms the data to a local coordinate system. A single point is expressed in both the global and local coordinate systems. Of course a picture really helps me to understand what is happening and if it is working correctly.
[image]

Have a good day and pay it forward.